# How to loop through an array of hashes to find a username in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, hash

I am trying to just loop through this array of hashes to find the username the user searches for. The issue is whenever i search for anything other than the first value it wont populate.

```
 users = [
          { username: "mashrur", password: "password1" },
          { username: "jack", password: "password2" },
          { username: "arya", password: "password3" },
          { username: "jonshow", password: "password4" },
          { username: "heisenberg", password: "password5" }
        ]
puts "Username"
temp_username = gets.chomp
users.each do |user_record|
  if user_record[:username] == temp_username
    puts "Succesfully Logged In"
    break
  else
    puts "Please try again"
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: Your selection of an answer suggests that you simply want to stop if the first username entered is not logged-in. If so, why the prompt, "Try again"? (Also, I don't know what you mean by "populate".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both branches of `if user_record[:username] == temp_username` use `break`.

This means that your loop will always finish after the first iteration.

As a suggestion, you can try to rewrite your code in the following way:

```rb
users = [
          { username: "mashrur", password: "password1" },
          { username: "jack", password: "password2" },
          { username: "arya", password: "password3" },
          { username: "jonshow", password: "password4" },
          { username: "heisenberg", password: "password5" }
        ]
puts "Username"
temp_username = gets.chomp

user = users.find { |user_record| user_record[:username] == temp_username }

if user
  puts "Succesfully Logged In"
else
  puts "Please try again"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your logic, you will `break` from the loop at the first element.
I guess you should change it a bit.

```
    ...
    temp_username = gets.chomp
    user = users.find { |u| u[:username] == temp_username }
```

if there any user with username equal to `temp_username` - it will assign the first one to `user` variable.
Then:

```
  if user
    puts "Succesfully Logged In"
  else
    puts "Please try again"
  end
```

Comment: A reminder that Ruby does not have Rail's method `present`. (No Rails tag.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to keep asking for a username until you find a user that is logged in; that is, until `h[:username]` equals the name entered for one of the hashes `h` in `users`. If so, you want to first construct a loop that displays the result for each username entered and provide a way to break out of the loop when a logged-in user is found.

```
loop do
  ...
  <display result for current user entry>
  <break if named user is logged in>
end
```

See [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop). You first need to obtain the name of the user.

```
loop do
  print "Username: "
  name = gets.chomp
  ...
  <display result for current user entry>
  <break if the value of name is logged in>
end
```

Now we need to *find* whether the value of `name` is logged in.

```
users = [
  { username: "mashrur", password: "password1" },
  { username: "jack", password: "password2" },
  { username: "arya", password: "password3" },
  { username: "jonshow", password: "password4" },
  { username: "heisenberg", password: "password5" }
]

loop do
  print "Username: "
  name = gets.chomp
  found = users.find { |h| h[:username] == name }
  ...
  <display result for current user entry>
  <break if the value of name is logged in>
end
```

See [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find). `find` returns the hash `h` for which `h[:username] == name` is `true` if `users` contains such a hash, else it returns `nil`.

The last step is to display the result and break from the loop if the named user is logged in.

```
loop do
  print "Username: "
  name = gets.chomp
  found = users.find { |h| h[:username] == name }
  puts found.nil? ? "Please try again" : "Succesfully Logged In"
  break unless found.nil?
end
```

Here is a sample conversation:

```
Username: bob
Please try again
Username: sue
Please try again
Username: jack
Succesfully Logged In
```